# How can I move an image automatically to a specific X,Y position on windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I move an image automatically to a specific X,Y position where I touch on the screen?

I have tried using ManipulationStarted but this is not working.

This is my code:

XML:

```
     <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txttouch" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtpoint" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image x:Name="imagenew"  Source="1.png" Height="30" Width="30">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transimage"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>


    </Grid>

  </Grid>
```

And C#:

```
private void ManipulationStartedonGrid(object sender,system.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)

        {
            transimage.X = e.ManipulationOrigin.X;
            transimage.Y = e.ManipulationOrigin.Y;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ManipulationOrigin` is obviously the fixed starting point of the manipulation. You should use something like `ManipulationDelta` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Canvas gives you an opportunity to explicitly set child position.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="imagenew"  Source="1.png" Height="30" Width="30">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="transimage"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>                             
   </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

In code set coords you need:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(imagenew, leftCoord);
Canvas.Settop(imagenew, topCoord);
```